# имитация нажатие на элемент select value

Tags: javascript, jquery

есть выпадающий список и снизу кнопки , при нажатие на кнопки выбирается из списка select по строке , мне нужно что бы выбиралось не по строке а по value

```js
$('#js-button-1').click(function(){
  $('#DropboxImage4166').val($('#DropboxImage4166 option').eq(1).val());
  $('#DropboxImage4166').change();
});
```

```html
<select id="DropboxImage4166" onchange="DropboxImageChange()" name="customProductData[468][64][4166]">
<option value="windy">windy</option>
<option value="1" selected="">1</option>
</select>
<a id="js-button-1">Первый элемент</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.btn-default').click(function(){
  $('#DropboxImage4166  option').prop('selected', false);
  $('#DropboxImage4166').change();
});

$('#js-button-1').click(function(){
  $('#DropboxImage4166').val($('#DropboxImage4166 option:first').val());
  $('#DropboxImage4166').change();
});
```

---

```
$('#DropboxImage4166').val($('#DropboxImage4166 option').eq(1).val());
```

Comment: спасибо большое! вы гений!)

Comment: @ЭлвинАлиев Ну что Вы! Пожалуйста. Успехов!

Comment: можно еще вопрос? как прописать не option:first а на пример дальше мне нужно будет для 7 элементов писать option(1) ? или как?

Comment: @ЭлвинАлиев `$('#DropboxImage4166 option').eq(1)`

Comment: странно теперь пропадает вообще в select строки

Comment: @ЭлвинАлиев при выполнении какого кода?

Comment: $('#js-button-1').click(function(){
  $('#DropboxImage4166').val($('$('#DropboxImage4166 option').eq(1));
  $('#DropboxImage4166').change();
});

Comment: @ЭлвинАлиев `.val()`-то все равно надо вызывать

Comment: если не сложно можно весь код? а то не хватает мозгов как вставить(

Comment: @ЭлвинАлиев в ответе

Comment: еще раз спасибо!

Comment: добрый день, есть еще вопрос) можно как то сделать что бы выбор было по value на пример нажимаешь на #js-button-1 и выбирается именно value="windy" а не по номеру строки

Comment: @ЭлвинАлиев `$('#DropboxImage4166').val("windy");`